# iPython notebook blank page anaconda distribution

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda

I am trying to run the [iPython notebook](http://ipython.org/notebook.html) on a Macbook 2011 using the [anaconda python distribution](https://store.continuum.io/). If I just run the

```
ipython
```

directly from the terminal everything works fine and I get the expected version

```
Python 2.7.5 |Anaconda 1.6.1 (x86_64)| (default, Jun 28 2013, 22:20:13)
```

If I instead run

```
ipython notebook
```

my default browser (chrome) opens the relevant page but all I see is a blank site.
I have tried several browsers (safari and firefox) whit the same problem. Note that I had to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error) question in order to get the notebook to start. I have also tried to upgrade to the newly linked iPython 1.0.0 such that

```
ipython                   1.0.0                    py27_0
ipython-notebook          0.13.2                   py27_0
ipython-qtconsole         0.13.2                   py27_0
```

If I want to upgrade the ipython-notebook I have to downgrade to ipython-0.13.2. The shown terminal output is

```
2013-08-14 19:30:14.893 [NotebookApp] Using existing profile dir: u'/Users/schr/Downloads/qutip-lectures-master/profile_default'
2013-08-14 19:30:14.898 [NotebookApp] Using MathJax from CDN: http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js
2013-08-14 19:30:14.911 [NotebookApp] Serving notebooks from local directory: /Users/schr/Downloads/qutip-lectures-master
2013-08-14 19:30:14.911 [NotebookApp] The IPython Notebook is running at: http://127.0.0.1:8888/
2013-08-14 19:30:14.911 [NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation).
2013-08-14 19:30:15.291 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (127.0.0.1) 0.70ms
2013-08-14 19:30:15.292 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/bootstrap/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.49ms
2013-08-14 19:30:15.296 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/requirejs/require.js (127.0.0.1) 0.71ms
2013-08-14 19:30:15.297 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery/jquery.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.59ms
2013-08-14 19:30:15.298 [tornado.access] WARNING | 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js (127.0.0.1) 0.57ms
```

Comment: What version of `ipython` do you have? Try `conda update ipython` to make sure you are using 1.0.0.

Comment: Tried this and did not work, see edit above.

Comment: Well it turned out that a clean install of anaconda made it all work. Thanks for the idea regarding the update.