# No plugin found for prefix 'presto-docs' in the current project - Presto Build failure

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, presto

This is the error I am getting while doing 'mvn clean install' .

No plugin found for prefix 'presto-docs' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/var/root/.m2/repository), sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException: No plugin found for prefix 'presto-docs' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.tomdz.maven, com.mycila, com.facebook.presto, org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local (/var/root/.m2/repository), sonatype-nexus-snapshots (https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)]

THE BUILD FAILED HERE :

 [INFO] --- sphinx-maven-plugin:1.0.3:generate (default) @ presto-docs ---

 [INFO] Unpacking sphinx to /Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx

 [ERROR] Exception in thread "main" javax.script.ScriptException: ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8 in  at line number 1

 [ERROR]    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:191)

 [ERROR]    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)

 [ERROR]    at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)

 [ERROR]    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)

 [ERROR]    at org.tomdz.maven.sphinx.SphinxRunner.run(SphinxRunner.java:59)

 [ERROR]    at org.tomdz.maven.sphinx.SphinxRunner.main(SphinxRunner.java:25)

 [ERROR] Caused by: Traceback (most recent call last):

 [ERROR]   File "", line 1, in 

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/sphinx/**init**.py", line 47, in main

 [ERROR]     from sphinx import cmdline

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/sphinx/**init**.py", line 47, in main

 [ERROR]     from sphinx import cmdline

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 18, in 

 [ERROR]     from docutils.utils import SystemMessage

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/docutils/utils/**init**.py", line 19, in 

 [ERROR]     from docutils.io import FileOutput

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/docutils/io.py", line 18, in 

 [ERROR]     from docutils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput

 [ERROR]   File "/Users/sprinklr/tools/presto/presto-docs/target/sphinx/docutils/error_reporting.py", line 47, in 

 [ERROR]     locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]

 [ERROR]   File "/private/var/root/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.5.2/jython-standalone-2.5.2.jar/Lib/locale.py", line 443, in  getdefaultlocale

 [ERROR]   File "/private/var/root/.m2/repository/org/python/jython-standalone/2.5.2/jython-standalone-2.5.2.jar/Lib/locale.py", line 375, in _parse_localename

 [ERROR] ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Please guide me to oversome this

Comment: The relevant error seems to be "ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8"

Comment: Can you show the output of the "env" command? Also, "mvn -v"?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8) question, running the following before Maven might fix it:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Though we should fix the Sphinx plugin to set everything correctly as the build should not be affected by your local environment variables.