# Error setup powerline for bash shell on Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, bash, powerline

I would like to use *powerline* with *bash* (not *zsh* if possible) but I have faced some errors, below are steps I have been through

I recently install *python* using *homebrew*

I have also executed `brew linkapps python`

I have installed *powerline-statys* using `pip install powerline-status`

I have extended my *~/.bash_profile*

```
if [ -f /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
    source /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

I also have installed patched fonts from https://github.com/powerline/fonts using it's `install.sh`

After Opennig new tab in *iTerm2* I have faced this error, I think it's about *python* but I have no ideas how to fix it, so please help

```
traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/powerline-config", line 6, in <module>
    from powerline.commands.config import get_argparser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/commands/config.py", line 6, in <module>
    import powerline.bindings.config as config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from powerline.commands.main import finish_args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/commands/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    encoding = get_preferred_arguments_encoding()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/lib/encoding.py", line 77, in get_preferred_arguments_encoding
    locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
   return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/powerline-config", line 6, in <module>
    from powerline.commands.config import get_argparser
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/commands/config.py", line 6, in <module>
    import powerline.bindings.config as config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/config.py", line 19, in <module>
    from powerline.commands.main import finish_args
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/commands/main.py", line 17, in <module>
    encoding = get_preferred_arguments_encoding()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/lib/encoding.py", line 77, in get_preferred_arguments_encoding
    locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

#### My Environment

```
python --version
Python 2.7.6

brew list python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/2to3
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/2to3-2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/2to3-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/easy_install
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/easy_install-2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/idle
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/idle2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/idle2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pip2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pydoc
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pydoc2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pydoc2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python2-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/python2.7-config
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pythonw
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pythonw2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/pythonw2.7
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/smtpd.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/smtpd2.7.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/smtpd2.py
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/bin/wheel
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/ (3761 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/IDLE.app/Contents/ (8 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/lib/pkgconfig/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/libexec/pip/ (499 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/libexec/setuptools/ (227 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/libexec/wheel/ (92 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Python Launcher.app/Contents/ (17 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/share/man/ (3 files)
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/share/python/ (315 files)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your python complains about the unknown locale UTF-8. Searching the net gives the following [solution](https://coderwall.com/p/-k_93g/mac-os-x-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-in-python). Add these lines to your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```