# Python - ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Tags: python, bash, pandas, osx-elcapitan

I run the python script that contain Pandas (that one cause the problem) library I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

But if I import from package path to make sure it detects Pandas library, I got this error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pandas
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 16, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2864, in <module>
    import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 28, in <module>
    import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/converter.py", line 7, in <module>
    import matplotlib.units as units
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
    encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

I already update my `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc` with these lines but still not working even I already restart the terminal and my machine.

```
export LANG="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_COLLATE="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_CTYPE="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_MESSAGES="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_MONETARY="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_NUMERIC="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"  
export LC_ALL="it_IT.UTF-8"
```

I'm also enabled `Set locale environment variables on startup` in the terminal preferences.

[image]

I'm afraid the problem caused because of El Capitan.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your terminal encoding, which only affects the display of text stream in the terminal.

Comment: I need to fix this. It will affect my result.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate question because set LC_ALL doesn't work for me. The solution works for me is to uncheck the Set locale env variables on startup at terminal's preferences.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit**: Pandas, and its dependencies, had [localization bugs](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/4918) that were discovered in non-C locales and fixed in recent versions.

When I downloaded the latest version of Pandas onto an OS X Yosemite computer via `sudo pip install pandas` in a terminal set to it_IT.UTF-8, and then imported it in a new Python session, I wasn't able to reproduce this issue.

My best guess now - and I'd emphasize this is only a guess - is that the version of Pandas in that folder predates those fixes and is broken in it_IT.UTF-8. (I do think this is, on balance, more likely than the issue being specific to El Capitan.)

---

<del>Your LC_ALL= is unset. That seems unusual; based on [other answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8) I think you should try setting it to LC_ALL="it_IT.UTF-8" and remove the other LC_ settings.</del>

<del>Then save your .bash_profile, open a new terminal tab, and try again.</del>

Comment: You actually contradict yourself... You probably meant `LC_ALL="it_IT.UTF-8"` in the code block.

Comment: Oops! Fixed now, thank you!

Comment: `LC_ALL` is _not_ normally set on OS X, but `LANG` is. You'd only need to set `LC_ALL` to override if someone else - unusually - had set `LC_ALL` too. Your `LC_ALL=...` command effectively overrides your `LANG=...` command - there is never a need for _both_.

Comment: I already update .bash_profile and restart my  terminal. But it still happen. Same error message.

Comment: To back up @mklement0's claim: `man locale`.

Comment: Browsed through `man locale`, and I understand I'm wrong here. This wouldn't change anything over OP's original locale settings.