# Settings for Locales in Coderunner Application with python 3 and matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, coderunner

I have been desperately looking for an answer for quite a while. My problem:

*The problem is:*

**With Python in Coderunner on a mac, I cannot import matplotlib, always getting:**

**unknown locale: UTF-8**

*A bit of historical details:*

I used Python 3.4 with Matplotlib using the **Coderunner** App for programming and running my scripts. Everything was fine. I changed to El Capitan - still everything great. Now I installed Python 3.5 (and was stupid enough to get rid of 3.4).

*What I tried so far:*

I tried tons of different settings in the locales setting of Coderunner, which is pre-set to variable LC_CTYPE and value UTF-8. I tried lots of de_DE, de_de, en_us, en_US, variations. I added LANGUAGE, LC_ALL and tried more combinations. I reinstalled python, matplotlib and so on dozens of times.

I am quite sure that it is a Coderunner settings issue, because matplotlib runs nicely when I use python3 via terminal.

Is there anybody out there with a solution for that?

Comment: Are you using the same interpreter in CodeRunner and terminal? Check what's the interpreter in terminal using `which python3` and compare it to the outcome of running this code via CodeRunner `from sys import executable` and then `print(executable)`. Are they the same?

Comment: me too but its w/ python 2.  did you figure it out?

Comment: @PouriaHadjibagheri hey my python is the same from terminal and coderunner but im getting same issue for pandas

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this post here:
[Pelican 3.3 pelican-quickstart error "ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8)

If you're using other program instead of Terminal, simply add `LC_ALL` and `LANG` as shell variables, then set their values to be `en_US.UTF-8`.