# ubuntu python anaconda2: cannot import matplotlib after activate tensorflow

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, tensorflow, anaconda

[Just as this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35526867/import-of-packages-does-not-work-probably-version-conflict), I use Ubuntu and Anaconda for python 2.7 to install tensorflow and then activate the environment by `source activate tensorflow` which is exactly the same as shown in official website. After activation, use `python` command to enter python environment, now I can `import tensorflow as tf` but I cannot `import matplotlib`.

Without activating tensorflow, the `import matplotlib` works but in that case I cannot `import tensorflow`. So is it a conflict? Can someone tell me how to solve it? Is there any way to keep tensorflow always activated so that I don't need to activate it everytime (my previous ubuntu do have this feature but I forgot how did I make it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing `matplotlib` using anaconda directly with `conda install matplotlib` from your `tensorflow` environment. One of the ideas of using anaconda is to keep environment self contained with the ability to avoid dependency conflicts (i.e. I don't see a point in activating the `tensorflow` for every new shell if you don't intend to use anaconda). You could either avoid the use of anaconda entirely and install tensorflow locally or export `source activate tensorflow` to your ~/.bashrc

Comment: Thanks mate, I installed matplotlib under tensorflow environment and it works. I'm currently only using cpu version of tensorflow so that I installed it through anaconda following its introduction. I'll switch to gpu version some days later to use CUDA. It's actually not takes too much time since I didn't close my terminal frequently. Anyway, thanks for your help, that's pretty nice.