# Cannot install Seaborn using pip, even after manually installing all the dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies, pip, seaborn

```
$ pip install seaborn

Collecting seaborn
  Using cached seaborn-0.7.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/hf/hf0xmv_d6mb0n4qp6xqkq0sh0000gn/T/pip-build-UpeZ8b/seaborn/setup.py", line 66, in <module>
        install_requires = check_dependencies()
      File "/private/var/folders/hf/hf0xmv_d6mb0n4qp6xqkq0sh0000gn/T/pip-build-UpeZ8b/seaborn/setup.py", line 54, in check_dependencies
        import matplotlib
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
        rcParams = rc_params()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
        return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
        config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
        with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
        return self.gen.next()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
        encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
        return _parse_localename(localename)
      File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.10_2/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
        raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
    ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/hf/hf0xmv_d6mb0n4qp6xqkq0sh0000gn/T/pip-build-UpeZ8b/seaborn
```

I have installed all the necessary dependencies for Seaborn(matplotlib, scipy, numpy, pandas, statsmodels; with no use whatsoever. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is a `locale` command output in terminal?

Comment: This looks like a problem with your matplotlib installation. What happens if you open up python and try to import matplotlib?

Comment: It works fine, I see no problem in importing and using matplotlib.

Comment: Run as Administrator solved my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a solution posted 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8)

in your `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: It works like charm. Thanks.

Comment: @YashwanthRemidi is this solved your problem, you should use the green checkmark to indicate it as such.

Comment: Done. Didn't knew that. Thanks.