# Jupyter note matplotlib inline error in Anaconda

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I launched notebook in Anaconda, and had the code in screenshot. I don't know what's wrong with my code.

[Link to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c9qhC.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually run the first cell. Notebook is essentially a thin wrapper over a Python shell, and by default, it just executes one cell at a time. The `[1]` indicates that you only ran the second cell.

Comment: When I run the first cell, it also has an error. ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8. I can add to my question

Comment: Sounds like you may have some other environment issue. Maybe try the suggestion here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8