# I'm trying to run skbio and keep getting 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbio.core'

Tags: python, python-3.x, skbio

I'm trying to run skbio in my python script and keep getting the error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'skbio.core.' I am on a Mac running Mojave version 10.14.3

I have tried the following:

1) Updating the bash script like so does not help (as advised by post [Pelican 3.3 pelican-quickstart error "ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8) ):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

nor does changing the default to Python 3

```
alias python=python3
```

2) I have re-installed scikit-bio several times using PIP

Here is the code I'm running:

```
from skbio.core.distance import DissimilarityMatrix

dm= DissimilarityMatrix.from_file(training_data)
```

I expect it should run (though not output anything yet) but keep getting stuck at the ModuleNotFoundError.

Any help would be great, thanks!!

Comment: Try running pip install scikit-bio