# Locale error in the Airflow while selecting a Dag

Tags: python, airflow, zsh, macos-catalina, airflow-scheduler

I just installed Airflow and ran an example DAG by using External Trigger(Play Button) option. When I go to *DagRuns* option I am getting the following exception. I used Airflow a couple of years back so I am unsure what is going wrong now. I also noticed this on top of the page

> The scheduler does not appear to be running.
>
> The DAGs list may not update, and new tasks will not be scheduled.

Though it is running.

```
  ((/  ( _(   )   (   _) ) (  () )  )
                    ( (  ( (_)   ((    (   )  .((_ ) .  )_
                   ( (  )    (      (  )    )   ) . ) (   )
                  (  (   (  (   ) (  _  ( _) ).  ) . ) ) ( )
                  ( (  (   ) (  )   (  ))     ) _)(   )  )  )
                 ( (  ( \ ) (    (_  ( ) ( )  )   ) )  )) ( )
                  (  (   (  (   (_ ( ) ( _    )  ) (  )  )   )
                 ( (  ( (  (  )     (_  )  ) )  _)   ) _( ( )
                  ((  (   )(    (     _    )   _) _(_ (  (_ )
                   (_((__(_(__(( ( ( |  ) ) ) )_))__))_)___)
                   ((__)        \\||lll|l||///          \_))
                            (   /(/ (  )  ) )\   )
                          (    ( ( ( | | ) ) )\   )
                           (   /(| / ( )) ) ) )) )
                         (     ( ((((_(|)_)))))     )
                          (      ||\(|(|)|/||     )
                        (        |(||(||)||||        )
                          (     //|/l|||)|\\ \     )
                        (/ / //  /|//||||\\  \ \  \ _)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Node: adnans-mbp.home
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2446, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1951, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1820, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1949, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1935, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 69, in inner
    return self._run_view(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 368, in _run_view
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_login/utils.py", line 258, in decorated_view
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 380, in view_func
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/utils.py", line 286, in wrapper
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/utils/db.py", line 74, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 1765, in graph
    show_external_logs=bool(external_logs))
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/views.py", line 389, in render
    return super(AirflowViewMixin, self).render(template, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/base.py", line 308, in render
    return render_template(template, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 140, in render_template
    ctx.app,
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/templating.py", line 120, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/asyncsupport.py", line 76, in render
    return original_render(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 1008, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 780, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/_compat.py", line 37, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/graph.html", line 22, in top-level template code
    {% import 'admin/static.html' as admin_static with context %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/dag.html", line 21, in top-level template code
    {% import 'admin/lib.html' as lib with context %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/master.html", line 20, in top-level template code
    {% extends "admin/master.html" %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html", line 20, in top-level template code
    {% extends 'admin/base.html' %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/templates/bootstrap3/admin/base.html", line 38, in top-level template code
    {% block page_body %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/admin/master.html", line 191, in block "page_body"
    {% block body %}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/airflow/www/templates/airflow/graph.html", line 40, in block "body"
    Base date: {{ form.base_date(class_="form-control") }}
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 155, in __call__
    return self.meta.render_field(self, kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/meta.py", line 56, in render_field
    return field.widget(field, **render_kw)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_admin/form/widgets.py", line 63, in __call__
    return super(DateTimePickerWidget, self).__call__(field, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/widgets/core.py", line 181, in __call__
    kwargs['value'] = field._value()
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 736, in _value
    return self.data and self.data.strftime(self.format) or ''
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pendulum/mixins/default.py", line 124, in strftime
    return self.format(fmt, _locale.getlocale()[0], 'classic')
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 587, in getlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/AdnanAhmad/Data/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/locale.py", line 495, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

Comment: This seems to be an OS related issue. Depending on your OS can you try `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8\ export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`.

Comment: @mad_ Already done no change

Comment: What OS are you using? You also mentioned the scheduler is not running. Do you know why?

Comment: No I do not know why is it saying not running while it is! I am using MacoS Catalina

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8

Comment: have already done it. No difference. Also Airflow Web says Schedular is not running while it is

Answer (score 1):

I spent several days with the issue

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

If you've already tried everything, check if your IDE is up to date. In my case, I just updated PyCharm from 2020 to 2021 and the problem disappeared.

Wish you all the best!