# ipython notebook installation on mac os x

Tags: macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am wondering if anyone has installed ipython notebook on mac OSX?

Currently I am able to run it in the **terminal note** but as soon as I type in the notebook version, there are problems encountered in running it.

Below is the error I have gotten:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/bin/ipython", line 9, in 
>       load_entry_point('ipython==2.0.0-dev', 'console_scripts', 'ipython')()   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/**init**.py",
>   line 118, in start_ipython
>       return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 565, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 314, in initialize
>       super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/application.py",
>   line 371, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 309, in parse_command_line
>       return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "", line 2, in parse_command_line   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 474, in parse_command_line
>       return self.initialize_subcommand(subc, subargv)   File "", line 2, in initialize_subcommand   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 92, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 405, in initialize_subcommand
>       subapp = import_item(subapp)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/importstring.py",
>   line 42, in import_item
>       module = **import**(package, fromlist=[obj])   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/html/notebookapp.py",
>   line 75, in 
>       from IPython.consoleapp import IPythonConsoleApp   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/consoleapp.py",
>   line 43, in 
>       from IPython.kernel.zmq.kernelapp import (   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/kernel/zmq/kernelapp.py",
>   line 54, in 
>       from .ipkernel import Kernel   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/kernel/zmq/ipkernel.py", line 40, in 
>       from .zmqshell import ZMQInteractiveShell   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/kernel/zmq/zmqshell.py", line 36, in 
>       from IPython.core.payloadpage import install_payload_page   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipython-2.0.0_dev-py2.7.egg/IPython/core/payloadpage.py",
>   line 24, in 
>       from docutils.core import publish_string   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/core.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       from docutils import frontend, io, utils, readers, writers   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/frontend.py",
>   line 41, in 
>       import docutils.utils   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/**init**.py",
>   line 20, in 
>       import docutils.io   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/io.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       from docutils.utils.error_reporting import locale_encoding, ErrorString, ErrorOutput   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/docutils/utils/error_reporting.py",
>   line 47, in 
>       locale_encoding = locale.getlocale()[1] or locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]   File
>   "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 511, in
>   getdefaultlocale
>       return _parse_localename(localename)   File "/Users/tayyangki/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 443, in
>   _parse_localename
>       raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Greatly appreciated if someone could help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook locale error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error)

Answer (score 1):

As noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8), the workaround for the "unknown locale: UTF-8" issue to add:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

to your to your ~/.bash_profile.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for the info but I have found out the problems a few weeks ago and have forgotten to post it here....

It is just that for Mac installation, it is pretty tricky and hence while installing, instead of typing in: easy_install ipython, users have to specify the python version.
Thus, I will need to type in easy_install ipython2.7

After which all is fine and working great!