# Can't find launcher in ~/anaconda 2.0 in mac osx

Tags: ipython, spyder, qtconsole

I just did a clean install of ananconda 2.0 (python 3.4) on my mac osx after uninstalling the previous version of anaconda. 
I used the graphical installer but the launcher is missing in the ~/anaconda directory.

I tried running spyder and ipython from the terminal but i got long error messages that ended with: 
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

I am a newbie to python programming and this is quite unnerving for me. I have gone through related answers but I still need help.

Guys, please kindly point me in the right direction.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook locale error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems here:

1. The Anaconda launcher haven't been ported to Python 3 yet, so that's why you can't find it.
2. To fix the `ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8` problem, you need to:

   - Open a terminal
   - Write this command on it

     `nano ~/.bashrc` (`nano` is terminal-based editor)
   - Paste this text in `nano`:

     `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

     `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`
   - Hit these keys to save: `Ctrl+O+Enter`, then `Ctrl+X` to exit.
   - Close that terminal, open a new one and try to start `spyder`. Everything should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank u Carlo Cordoba.