# matplotlib import error in os x el capitan

Tags: python, matplotlib, homebrew, anaconda, osx-elcapitan

`import matplotlib` shows the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1130, in <module>
rcParams = rc_params()
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 974, in rc_params
return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1099, in rc_params_from_file
config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1017, in _rc_params_in_file
with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 18, in __enter__
return self.gen.next()
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 999, in _open_file_or_url
encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
return _parse_localename(localename)
File "/Users/user/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'
```

The same errors show when - `from matplotlib import pyplot` - is used. At first I thought the problem was because I didn't install matplotlib correctly. I initially tried with homebrew's python and after surfing through hundreds of guides on how to install it correctly, gave up out of sheer frustration. Then I tried with anaconda's python and again I got the same errors. Could someone please help me out here?

Comment: In bash, what does `locale` return?

Comment: @unutbu    LANG=    LC_COLLATE="C"    LC_CTYPE="UTF-8"    LC_MESSAGES="C"    LC_MONETARY="C"    LC_NUMERIC="C"    LC_TIME="C"    LC_ALL=

Comment: In python, what does `import locale; print(locale.getdefaultlocale())`  return?

Comment: @unutbu  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/vigneshprasad/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Users/vigneshprasad/anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename

Comment: Your symptoms seem similar to those in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15526996/190597). Perhaps try the solution posted there.

Comment: @unubtu Thanks!!! It worked!!!

Comment: Yay! I'm going to close this as a dup of http://stackoverflow.com/q/15526996/190597 then.