# Error importing Pandas

Tags: python-2.7

I am this error importing pandas. Can someone give me some hints? I have installed the pandas package.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/**init**.py", line 44, in

```
from pandas.core.api import *
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 9, in

```
from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 17, in

```
from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 41, in

```
from pandas.core.series import Series
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 2909, in

```
import pandas.tools.plotting as _gfx
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tools/plotting.py", line 28, in

```
import pandas.tseries.converter as conv
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/tseries/converter.py", line 7, in

```
import matplotlib.units as units
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1131, in

```
rcParams = rc_params()
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 975, in rc_params

```
return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file

```
config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file

```
with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in **enter**

```
return self.gen.next()
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url

```
encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale

```
return _parse_localename(localename)
```

File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename

```
raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
```

ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook locale error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after some more searching.

Basically, add some lines to your ~/.bash_profile:

export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8