# matplotlib does not import in python3

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have OSX El capitan, and get the following error when trying to import matplotlib in python 3:

```
 >>> import matplotlib
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/contextlib.py", line 59, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
    encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 559, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/locale.py", line 487, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError('unknown locale: %s' % localename)
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

I tried to delete the matplotlib folder, and reinstall it with pip install matplotlib, which it recreates it, but it ends up giving the same error.
I already spend half the weekend trying to find an answer but no luck - maybe somebody can help.
Best

Comment: Also see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution [here](https://coderwall.com/p/-k_93g/mac-os-x-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-in-python). Basically what you have to do is add two lines to your ~/.bash_profile (and re-open terminal window):

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot and have a nice weekend.