# Pandas Module Error - No attribute Core, Module can not be found

Tags: python, pandas

Aloha,

Windows 10, python 3.6. Originally install pandas with "python -m pip install pandas". After receiving the following error i uninstalled it by cd'ing to it's location under the python directory. I installed Anaconda, but i receive the same two errors as i did before.

the top of my file looks like:

```
    import pandas as pd
```

This is the error i receive in terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sdr-research\Dropbox (PCC)\SDR6\Qualtrics_Data\QualtricsSurveyResponses\mindshareResponsesPull.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3978, in <module>
    Series._add_series_or_dataframe_operations()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 8891, in _add_series_or_dataframe_operations
    from pandas.core import window as rwindow
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\window.py", line 36, in <module>
    import pandas._libs.window as _window
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

if i open python and then call pandas it returns the error below sometimes, other times the error above.

```
Python 3.6.5 (v3.6.5:f59c0932b4, Mar 28 2018, 17:00:18) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pandas
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\api.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\groupby\groupby.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 74, in <module>
    from pandas.core.series import Series
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 66, in <module>
    import pandas.core.ops as ops
AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

additionally, pip list returns pandas as a module present. So i know it is there, i think it is just a bad installation or something is wrong with pandas itself stopping it from running.

```
PS C:\Users\sdr-research> python -m pip list
Package           Version
----------------- ---------
altgraph          0.15
astroid           1.6.4
certifi           2018.4.16
chardet           3.0.4
colorama          0.3.9
future            0.16.0
idna              2.6
isort             4.3.4
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
macholib          1.9
mccabe            0.6.1
numpy             1.14.3
pandas            0.23.0
pefile            2017.11.5
pip               10.0.1
PyInstaller       3.3.1
pylint            1.9.1
pypiwin32         223
python-dateutil   2.7.3
pytz              2018.4
pywin32           223
requests          2.18.4
setuptools        39.0.1
six               1.11.0
urllib3           1.22
wrapt             1.10.11
```

Any suggestions?

Mahalo.

Comment: maybe this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c

Comment: It did not. I tried all of those options and none removed the error i am seeing.