# ImportError when I try to import DataFrame from pandas

Tags: python, pandas

QUESTION : When i try to run "`from pandas import read_csv`" or "`from pandas import DataFrame`", I get an error saying "`ImportError: cannot import name 'read_csv'`" and "`[![ImportError: cannot import name 'DataFrame'][1]][1]`" respectively.

CODE THAT I AM TRYING TO RUN:

```
    from pandas import DataFrame
    from sklearn import datasets 
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    data = pandas.DataFrame(iris)
    kfold = KFold(10, True, 1)
    for train, test in kfold.split(data):
print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))
```

WHAT I TRIED : I checked each and every import error question on stackoverflow and github but I couldn't figure out the solution.
I don't have any other file named pandas.py. 
I tried uninstalling and reinstalling all the packages(like scipy, scikit-learn, numpy, pandas)
I tried updating all the packages, but no luck
Application specifications that i have - Windows 10, version 1803, Anaconda 4.5.8, spyder 3.3.0

Infact, none of my other code, which was running successfully previously, isn't executing because of these ImportErrors. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

This is the result of "pip show pandas"
[image]

This is the result of "conda search -f pandas"
[image]

Comment: if you are importing only "DataFrame" from pandas. you should only be doing:
data = DataFrame(iris) and not data = pandas.DataFrame(iris)

Comment: [Check out this SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c)

Comment: I had checked it long back. I had python version 0.18 and upgraded to 0.22 but now I am getting "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'" error!

Comment: @Smr how did you install pandas? `conda install pandas` ?

Comment: Yes conda install pandas, and then i did conda update pandas and then i tried pip install pandas==0.22 too

Answer (score 3):

You have already imported `DataFrame` in statement `from pandas import DataFrame`.

So you don't need to use `pandas.DataFrame`, you can just use `DataFrame` instead.

But my suggestion will be using `import pandas as pd`, with this you can use all the submodules of pandas.

Use below code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets 
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame(iris)
kfold = KFold(10, True, 1)
for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data[train], data[test]))
```

Comment: No luck. I tried running it as specified above but i get "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'" error.

Comment: This is the solution if case is `NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined`

Comment: I have already mentioned in my question that i DON'T HAVE any pandas.py file. Also, this is the only error message it is showing. I have attached a screenshot

Comment: Can you get the trace of `pip show pandas`? and check `which python` too.

Comment: I have python 3.5.5 and I have edited my question to show the trace of "pip show pandas"

Comment: what is the version of your pandas?

Comment: @Smr Since you're using conda, get this trace too. 

`conda search -f pandas`

Comment: Now, `conda search --outdated`. This will show you the outdated package. Latest pandas version is `v0.23.3`. So `conda update --all`.

Comment: No luck after updating as well @Sleeba Paul

Answer (score 1):

You know what is wrong? Your file name `pandas.py` This is funny but a tricky problem no one would easily notice. In fact, when you want to import a library, python first looks into the current folder, then all the python paths defined. Here, you try to import `pandas`, python first get your `pandas.py` and look for `DataFrame`. But there is no `DataFrame` in it which can be imported.

Change your filename and that's it. In future, don't name your files with standard library names.

Answer (score 1):

If `pandas` and `sklearn` is correctly installed, this should work:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets 
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
iris = datasets.load_iris()
data = pd.DataFrame(iris.data,columns = iris.feature_names)
kfold = KFold(10, True, 1)
for train, test in kfold.split(data):
    print('train: %s, test: %s' % (data.iloc[train], data.iloc[test]))
```

Comment: I actually cross-checked whether i have installed sklearn and pandas correctly. I even updated those packages. But i still encounter the same "AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'" error

Comment: Which pandas version have you installed?  check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36521691/7699859) @Smr

Comment: I have pandas (0.18.1)