# AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_libs'

Tags: pandas, anaconda, jupyter

whenever i try to `import pandas` in `jupyter notebook`, i get the error as following:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_libs'

How to fix it? i am just new to programming

Comment: You likely have mismatch/conflict of versions.. could be many things. Make sure you are using python 3 and installed the most up-to-date pandas for python 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36649229/7470786 Your question already has an answer here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Importing Pandas gives error AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core' in iPython Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c)

Answer (score 3):

Close the terminal. Restart jupyter notebook / lab fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this error as well, and just fixed it by just updating conda & pandas while using Anaconda

Answer (score 0):

I used to get the same:

> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute '_libs' error

Whenever I used to open the old file in Jupyter notebook, but you can open a new file and then try importing the Pandas it will work.