# After upgrading to tensorflow 2.0, I get the error to import tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, anaconda, upgrade, updates

I have installed tensorflow via anaconda about year ago. Now I upgrade tensorflow to tensorflow 2.0.0-beta1 with this lines in cmd:

```
conda update --all
pip install --upgrade tensorflow==2.0.0-beta1
```

Installation successful With this final comment:

```
Successfully installed google-pasta-0.1.7 tb-nightly-1.14.0a20190603 tensorflow-2.0.0b1 tf-estimator-nightly-1.14.0.dev2019060501
```

But when I import tensorflow I get this error:

```
import tensorflow

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: where did you import it? terminal or notebook?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c)? The [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18042) raised against tensorflow on github references this page as a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below command

```
conda upgrade --all
```

If you are using jupyter notebook restart the book and then try to import tensorflow

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks alot. I am using spyder. With restarting it, problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Create an environment using following code snippet.
`conda create -n myenv python=3.4`
Install all the libraries including Tensorflow in this environment so that there won't be any compatibility issues.
Note: Some libraries come inbuilt when you create environment according to python version you specified.