# I am getting attribute error while importing pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, attributeerror

I was importing pandas in jupyter notebook but it gives an error stating that `module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'`

here my code snippet

```py
import pandas as pd
```

and this is the error I got while importing

> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)  in 
>   ----> 1 import pandas as pd
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas__init__.py in 
>       194 # GH 27101
>       195 # TODO: remove Panel compat in 1.0
>   --> 196 if pandas.compat.PY37:
>       197 
>       198     def **getattr**(name):
>
> AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'compat'

How to solve this, guys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c

Comment: Is `pandas` installed?

Comment: This is most probably a version issue. If you are on 0.25.0+ downgrade to 0.23.0 or lower.

Comment: try upgrading pandas

Answer (score 0):

Could be that your packages are conflicting.

Perhaps try

```
conda upgrade --all -y
```

Answer (score 0):

1ST METHOD

Go to anaconda navigator and install the `pandas` module

2ND METHOD

Type `pip install pandas` in anaconda prompt
later you will run pandas in the script you will succeed