# Cannot import tpot: ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_object'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, anaconda, tpot

I've installed all the dependencies, so I'm not sure why I keep getting this error when I try to import tpot.

```
<ipython-input-1-70f222d22a16> in <module>()
----> 1 import tpot

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tpot/__init__.py in <module>()
     26 from ._version import __version__
     27 from .tpot import TPOTClassifier, TPOTRegressor
---> 28 from .driver import main

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tpot/driver.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 import numpy as np
---> 27 import pandas as pd
     28 import argparse
     29 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.tseries.api import *

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
      8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, isnull, notna, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
---> 10 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
     11 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
     12 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
      3     Grouper, GroupBy, SeriesGroupBy, DataFrameGroupBy
      4 )

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in <module>()
     44 from pandas.core.base import (PandasObject, SelectionMixin, GroupByError,
     45                               DataError, SpecificationError)
---> 46 from pandas.core.index import (Index, MultiIndex,
     47                                CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index)
     48 from pandas.core.arrays import ExtensionArray, Categorical

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.indexes.api import *
      3 from pandas.core.indexes.multi import _sparsify

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py in <module>()
      2 import warnings
      3 
----> 4 from pandas.core.indexes.base import (Index,
      5                                       _new_Index,
      6                                       _ensure_index,

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in <module>()
     51 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject, IndexOpsMixin
     52 import pandas.core.common as com
---> 53 from pandas.core import ops
     54 from pandas.util._decorators import (
     55     Appender, Substitution, cache_readonly, deprecate_kwarg)

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/ops/__init__.py in <module>()
     21     maybe_upcast_putmask,
     22 )
---> 23 from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
     24     ensure_object,
     25     is_bool_dtype,

ImportError: cannot import name 'ensure_object'
```

And when I try to use `from tpot import TPOTClassifier` it gives me another error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d4601c9d8e34> in <module>()
----> 1 from tpot import TPOTClassifier

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tpot/__init__.py in <module>()
     26 from ._version import __version__
     27 from .tpot import TPOTClassifier, TPOTRegressor
---> 28 from .driver import main

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tpot/driver.py in <module>()
     25 
     26 import numpy as np
---> 27 import pandas as pd
     28 import argparse
     29 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py in <module>()
     40 import pandas.core.config_init
     41 
---> 42 from pandas.core.api import *
     43 from pandas.core.sparse.api import *
     44 from pandas.tseries.api import *

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py in <module>()
      8 from pandas.core.dtypes.missing import isna, isnull, notna, notnull
      9 from pandas.core.arrays import Categorical
---> 10 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import Grouper
     11 from pandas.io.formats.format import set_eng_float_format
     12 from pandas.core.index import (Index, CategoricalIndex, Int64Index,

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import (
      3     Grouper, GroupBy, SeriesGroupBy, DataFrameGroupBy
      4 )

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py in <module>()
     44 from pandas.core.base import (PandasObject, SelectionMixin, GroupByError,
     45                               DataError, SpecificationError)
---> 46 from pandas.core.index import (Index, MultiIndex,
     47                                CategoricalIndex, _ensure_index)
     48 from pandas.core.arrays import ExtensionArray, Categorical

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py in <module>()
      1 # flake8: noqa
----> 2 from pandas.core.indexes.api import *
      3 from pandas.core.indexes.multi import _sparsify

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/api.py in <module>()
      2 import warnings
      3 
----> 4 from pandas.core.indexes.base import (Index,
      5                                       _new_Index,
      6                                       _ensure_index,

/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in <module>()
     50 
     51 from pandas.core.base import PandasObject, IndexOpsMixin
---> 52 import pandas.core.common as com
     53 from pandas.core import ops
     54 from pandas.util._decorators import (

AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'
```

Comment: Try to reinstall Pandas via `conda install pandas --force-reinstall`

Comment: @James, I did the same error for both now, ´´´AttributeError: module 'pandas' has no attribute 'core'´´´

Comment: Do you by any chance switch languages on your computer?  See this q/a: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36521691/importing-pandas-gives-error-attributeerror-module-pandas-has-no-attribute-c