# Unable to import and use pandas with django in anaconda virtual env

Tags: django, pandas

I am working on a django project in which it is required to use pandas,mostly for creating dataframe using read_csv method. I am working in a conda virtual env in which pandas is installed as i checked it with :`conda list`
But when i run the file in which i have to import pandas, it shows a valuerror

```
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

To check if the python version is correct, I tried to import pandas in python shell in same virtual env but I still got he same error.
I dont know why i am getting this though pandas is installed in the env.

Here is the screenshort of error I get after trying the two solutions:
[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961239/pelican-3-3-pelican-quickstart-error-valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8

Comment: i tried both of them but still got the sam error in python shell and in conda virtual env.

Comment: I got it correct. Actually both of the solutions partially worked for me but most important is to restart the Mac so that changes are applied to .bash_profile properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IPython Notebook locale error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15526996/ipython-notebook-locale-error)

Answer (score 0):

Just add these two line in your .bash_profile, (if you are on bash)
`export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8`
and source it, or restart the terminal.
Or if you are using "oh my zsh" shell, then
add the lines in .zshrc.