# Spacy link error

Tags: python, models, spacy

When running:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

the following is printed:

> Warning: no model found for 'en'
>   Only loading the 'en' tokenizer.

`/site-packages/spacy/data` is empty with the exception of the init file.
all filepaths are only pointing to my single installation of python.

Any help appreciated on resolving this.

Thanks!
Will

Comment: Hi Will, if any of the answers here solved your problem, kindly accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I had this same issue when I tried this on Windows 10 - the problem was the output of `python -m spacy.en.download all` said `Linking successful` but above that was the message that the symbolic link wasn't actually created, due to permissions.

Running `python -m spacy.en.download all` as an Adminstrator fixed the problem.

Comment: Using Ubuntu putting `sudo python -m spacy.en.download all` solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: Syntax changed in the latest version to "python -m spacy download en".

Comment: I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.gold'

Answer (score 7):

You might need to install the specific module too after installing spacy. 
Try:

> python -m spacy.en.download all

Here is the reference link: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spacy

Answer (score 7):

run cmd as an administrator ,then download the model en package

```
python -m spacy download en
```

Comment: That helps.
if you're using Mac OS, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916461/valueerror-unknown-locale-utf-8-when-importing-pandas-in-python-2-7/38917471#38917471)

Comment: nothing worked, but this solved the problem: thanks 

Answer (score 6):

> If you’ve installed a model via pip, you can also import it directly
>   and then call its load() method:

**python -m spacy download en**

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_.load()
doc = nlp(u'This is a sentence.')
```

Comment: This helped me as I dont have admin permissions on work laptop. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had a previous installation of spacy that had created the symlink.

```
ls -al "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/data/en"
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root staff 74 Dec  5 00:40 /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/data/en -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/en_core_web_sm/en_core_web_sm-1.2.0

rm "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/spacy/data/en"

python3 -m spacy download en
```

And then everything is good.

Answer (score 3):

This works for Ubuntu users.

```
sudo python -m spacy download en
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use spaCy's [`download`](https://spacy.io/usage/models#download) command, it will create shortcut links automatically.

```sh
python -m spacy download en
```

But if you already have downloaded the model, you don't need to download it again, you can create a link using the [`link`](https://spacy.io/usage/models#usage-link) command.

```sh
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en
```

Answer (score 1):

I got around this by simply importing the model instead of performing nlp = spacy.load('en')

Comment: Please put this as a comment under question as it seems more like a partial answer at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If `python -m spacy download en` does not work for you (permissions, etc.), you can download the model first and then `pip install` it. For example, this is for version 2.3:

https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0/en_core_web_sm-2.3.0.tar.gz

The .tar.gz archive is the same file that's downloaded during `spacy download`, and is installable:

```
pip install /path/to/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

Then you can do:

```
import en_core_web_sm

nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the existing one

   ```
   pip uninstall spacy
   ```
2. install the spacy

   ```
   pip install spacy==2.3.5
   ```
3. Support for Spacy 3 was added. In prior versions of Rasa Open Source, to install spaCy with its language model for the English language, you need to additionally run python3 -m spacy link en_core_web_md en.

   ```
   python -m spacy download en_core_web_md 

   once symbolic link created for C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\envs\RasaBot\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en <<===>> C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\envs\RasaBot\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_md
   ✔ Linking successful
   C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\envs\RasaBot\lib\site-packages\en_core_web_md -->
   C:\Users\ABC\Anaconda3\envs\RasaBot\lib\site-packages\spacy\data\en
   You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')
   ```

Answer (score -1):

In windows user name can be added in "Create symbolic link" in "Local security policy" before downloading en. It is working for me.

Answer (score -2):

First you need to train the model. After training, You need to go through a saving and loading process. After that, I hope It'll work. Good Luck.
Since they updated the spacy version, find it  [Here](http://alpha.spacy.io/docs/usage/saving-loading)

Comment: No, you don't need to train the default English models that Spacy provides.