# Can't load the spaCy 'en' module

Tags: python, python-3.x, spacy

So I'm trying to get space to work but it's giving me this error:

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.

I have tried installing the module through the console, like 'python -m spacy download en' and a lot of other variations I found online to no success. I also tried to change spacy.load('en') to spacy.load('en_core_web_sm').

Answer (score 0):

You may need to attempt installation in both the correct path and as an admin as stated in this post:

[Spacy link error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459437/spacy-link-error)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` before you can use `nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")`.

`en` is a special case - it's a symbolic link. If you ran `python -m spacy download en`, what was the output? Was the symbol link created correctly?

More info here: https://spacy.io/usage/models

Comment: I already tried to download that too, like I said I tried a lot of different combinations.
The output said something along 'Link created successfully' and it said 'you can now use spacy.load('en')' as well as saying 'you can now use spacy.load('en_core_web_sm'). ' before that.

I checked my anaconda folder and it's there. Apparently I can even load it in the python shell with spacy.load('en'). So maybe the issue is PyCharm. But I have no idea how to deal with it right now

Answer (score 0):

After you download the 'en' or 'en_core_web_sm' or any model,

You may validate your spaCy's version and installed model using this command:

```
python -m spacy validate
```

Then if you want to change the shortcut link to the model, you can use this command:

```
python -m spacy link [package name or path] [shortcut] [--force]
```

So for example in your case:

```
python -m spacy link en en_default
```

Or for 'en_core_web_sm':

```
python -m spacy link en_core_web_sm en_default
```

Then to load, just use:

```
spacy.load("en_default")
```

Check out [spaCy's shortcut link](https://spacy.io/usage/models#usage-link)